# Trigonometry and complex numbers

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers, products, trigonometric-series

Suppose $z_0=e^{i\theta_0}$ a complexe number as $\theta_0\in ]-\pi,\pi[ \setminus\{0\}$.

For $n\in \mathbb{N}$, we pose $z_{n+1}=\dfrac{|z_n|+z_n}{2}$ and $z_n=r_ne^{i\theta_n}$ with $\left(r_n,\theta_n\right)\in \mathbb{R}^+ \times ]-\pi,\pi]$.

The first question was determine $r_{n+1}$ and $\theta_{n+1}$ using $r_{n}$ and $\theta_{n}$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

And I found that $r_{n+1} = r_n\cos\left(\dfrac{\theta_n}{2}\right)$ and $\theta_{n+1}=\dfrac{\theta_n}{2}$.

but I need to conclude that

> $$\forall n\in\mathbb{N}^*,
> > r_n=\Pi_{k=1}^n\cos\left(\dfrac{\theta_0}{2^k}\right)$$

The second problem is:

We put $n\in\mathbb{N} y_n=\operatorname{Im}\left(z_n\right)$.

and I need to calculate

> $y_{n+1}$ using $y_n$.

Then to conclude  that

> $$\forall n\in \mathbb{N}^*,
> > \Pi_{k=1}^n\cos\left(\dfrac{\theta_0}{2^k}\right)=\dfrac{\sin\theta_0}{2^n\sin\dfrac{\theta_0}{2^n}}$$

Comment: Um, so what is your question?

Comment: the question is to conclude the first equality then to write $y_n+1$ in function of yn and finally to conclude the last equality

Comment: What is YOUR question?

Comment: the QUESTIONS with grey backgrounds

Comment: Neither of the things shown in grey background appear to be questions.

Comment: The most important question is how to conclude $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}^*,
> r_n=\Pi_{k=1}^n\cos\left(\dfrac{\theta_0}{2^k}\right)$ fro; the result I've found

Comment: x @pourjour: By induction on $n$? Note that $\theta_k=\frac{\theta_0}{2^k}$.

Comment: that's make sense

Answer (score 1):

For the last equality:
 Multiply and divide $\Pi_{k=1}^n\cos\dfrac{\theta_0}{2^k}\;$ by $\sin\dfrac{\theta_0}{2^k}$ and use the trigonometric identity $$\sin{2\varphi}=2\sin{\varphi}\cos{\varphi}.$$

Comment: That may be a way to prove it, but is clearly not the geometric argument suggested by the exercise.